# How to put vertical line to http GET request without URI encoding

Tags: c#, http, get, uri, special-characters

I'm creating an C# app which have to send http GET requests with vertical line symbol inside URI query part and that is impossible due to url encoding by URI class. So in the final url is "%7C" instead of "|" and server app cannot handle it.
The main problem is, that the server side app is developed by our external supplier and I have no access to it's source code and they cannot edit it for some reason, so I really need to do it somehow inside my client app.

I've tryed a lot, but cannot find any solution on the internet. But I have two work-arounds that can almost do what I want:

**1) Using sockets**

It's works perfectly, but... when I use it asynchoniously, server app seems to cannot handle more sockets at one time, and always run only once, with same response to each socket GET request. Client sockets has same host (my local PC) but run on different local PC port.

**2) Using WebBrowser control with Navigate method**

Even this solution works almost fine, but I realy don't want to use WebBrowser for every GET request.

**Socket GET caller method**

```
    private static async Task<string> HttpGetRequestAsync(string url, int timeOut)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            timeOut += Environment.TickCount;

            Uri uri = new Uri(url);

            using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
            {
                socket.Connect(uri.Host, uri.Port);

                string request = string.Format(
                    "GET {0} HTTP/1.1{2}" +
                    "Host: {1}{2}" +
                    "Content-Length: 0{2}" +
                    "{2}", Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.PathAndQuery), uri.Host, "\r\n");

                socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request));

                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] responseData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                int bytesRead = socket.Receive(responseData);

                while (bytesRead != 0)
                {
                    if (timeOut < Environment.TickCount) { throw new TimeoutException("TimeOut exception...!"); }

                    response.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(responseData), 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = socket.Receive(responseData);
                }

                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();

                return response.ToString();
            }
        });
    }
```

So I really need to find a way, how to send GET request in this format:

> http://server:port/sms/send_sms.php?value1|value2

instead of this:

> http://server:port/sms/send_sms.php?value1%7Cvalue2

Comment: This is not an encoding issue but the Special Characters in html.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  Net Library has built in methods to do conversion : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: Yes, we both mean the same. :) I know these methods, you can see Uri.UnescapeDataString in my code which is very similar. But still.. there is the url formating problem where the URI class transforms (instead of "encodes" word) the url.

Comment: The you really have an Encoding issue.  ASCII characters 0x00 to 0x7F are always the same.  Characters 0x80 to 0xFF is different depending on the country/language.  So it looks like you need to use instead of ASCII Encoding use one of the windows encoding 1250,1251,1252, 1291.  The http header in the request/response has the country/language and you need to put in the correct header so the encoding is correct.

Comment: This could be a FONT issue and if the Font specified is not install on PC windows will use a similar FONT that displays character incorrectly.  Also if somebody inserted a Unicode character into the document you may be seeing the character for 1/2 of the Unicode character if you are only using a 8-bit encoding.

Comment: I think that this is misunderstanding. The vertical line is a unsafe url character and we should never use it in it. For this and many other reasons URI class from system.dll assembly automatically encodes this character into %7C format. So I'm looking for a way to prevent it. :)

Comment: Also, in GET requests we work with bytes, so there should not be any problem with font. And we even not showing anything on UI.

Comment: If you are working with bytes then you have to encode to a string.  Now if the data was in unicode and you are trying to encode back to an 8 bit encoding you will have issues.  The problem seems to be on the sending end and not in the receiver code.  You have to find out why the character was put in the document to get to root cause of issue.

Comment: With my code above, everything works perfect except that server app cannot work with multiple sockets async. But encoding there is OK with standard UTF8. The problem with HttpClient, HttpWebRequest, WebClient is that they are using Uri object and Uri have a native function, to translate unsupported characters to this format. So instead "|" i'm calling url with "%7C". But the server app dont use any standard back encoding for these cases. So it's read the URI query like "value1|value 2", but it's never find the pipe/vertical line delimiter and thinks that it's just a long valu1 without value2.

Comment: You are creating your own custom encoding.  So you must translate the request and insert the "|" when sending the request and must replace the "|" in the response unless you change the server.  The server will not recognize your %7C but should recognize &verbar; or &#7C;

Comment: I'll be happy if you are right. But i dont know how to do it. Can you please put here some example code using HttpClient, HttpWebRequest or WebClient?

Comment: The character is shown on following webpage : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references  You should be able to just use a string replace.

Comment: There is only one moment when you can do the replace, and that is before putting url to Uri object. You cannot modify it after. And server application waiting specificaly on vertical line and has no decoding because one parameter is phone number with + symbol on the start. So I dont think that any string replace will help, it just cannot. I have to use | in query.. nothing else